# How to get a value between a span with DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript

exemple.html

```
 <span id='char'>{{value}}</span>
```

exemple.ts

```
console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('char')))
```

This will display

```
<span id='char'>ThisIsTheValueupdated</span>
```

And in my exemple I want to get `ThisIsTheValueupdated`.

Comment: `console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('char').textContent))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `textContent` of the `span` which you have fetched

```
console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('char').textContent))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the text inside the tag instead using **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** or **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** :

```
console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('char').textContent));
or
console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('char').innerHTML));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

- [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) [nonstandard]), e.g.: `document.getElementById('char').textContent`
- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) and [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue), e.g., `document.getElementById('char').firstChild.nodeValue` if it's really just a single text node

More to explore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

Answer (score 0):

```
        <span id="text">inner text</span>       

        if you are using just javascript then

        var span_value = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

        console.log(span_value);

        If you are using jQuery then

        var span_value = $("#text").text();

        console.log(span_value);
```